# How to update the value of a variable inside foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

How to update the value of `$total` inside the foreach loop below? This is because I want to add a new row after each rowspan of Branch Column for `Branch Total` at the same time it is needed to update the value of `$total` for rowspan.

```
<tbody>
    <?php
      $count = 0;
      $count2 = 0;
      $count3 = 0;

      $total = 0;
      $total2 = 0;

    foreach ($reNominalRoll as $key => $value) {
        if ($row_area->ADMIN_ID == $value->AREA_ID) {
            $gTotalBorn += $value->Borne;
            $gTotalSanc += $value->sanction;

            $total = rowspan_count_groupby($reNominalRoll, 'ship', $value->ShipName, $value->PostingName, $value->Branch);
            $total2 = rowspan_count_groupby($reNominalRoll, 'unit', $value->ShipName, $value->PostingName, $value->Branch);

            ?>
            <tr class="allrow">
                <!--Ship Col-->
                <?php
                if ($count != 0)
                    $count--;
                else {
                    echo "<td rowspan=" . ($total) . ">" . $value->ShipName . "</td>";
                    $count = $total - 1;
                }
                ?>

                <!--Posting Col-->
                <?php
                if ($count2 != 0) {
                    $count2--;
                } else {
                    echo "<td rowspan=" . ($total2 + 1) . ">" . $value->PostingName . "</td>";
                    $count2 = $total2 - 1;
                }
                ?>

                <!--Branch Col-->
                <?php
                if ($count3 != 0)
                    $count3--;
                else {
                    echo "<td rowspan=" . ($total2 + 1) . ">" . $value->Branch . "</td>";
                    $count3 = $total2 - 1;
                }
                ?>

                <td><?php echo $value->Rank ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->Part ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->sanction;
                    $bTotalSanc += $value->sanction; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->Borne;
                    $bTotalBorn += $value->Borne; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->TotalIn ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->TotalOut ?></td>
            </tr>

            <!--Branch Total Row-->
            <?php
            if ($count3 == 0) {
                $total += 1;

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'>Branch Total</td>";
                echo "<td style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'>" . $bTotalSanc . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'>" . $bTotalBorn . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'></td>";
                echo "<td style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'></td>";
                echo "<td style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                $bTotalSanc = 0;
                $bTotalBorn = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    ?>

    <!--Grand Total Row-->
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" colspan="5">Grand Total</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $gTotalSanc; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $gTotalBorn; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**Here is the screenshot**
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rXei.png)

Please help me

Comment: where is your $count ?

Comment: all these `$count2` and `$total1` etc variables make my eyes gloss over.

Comment: I have given the total count @BILALMALIK

Comment: Branch Column variable for branch count should be count3?